# Styling Google Api GET request

Tags: php, html, css, api

Im trying to figure out how to style result like formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,location, ect. from a google api GET request. I know the incoming data will be look like this.

```
 "html_attributions" : [],
 "result" : {
  "formatted_address" : "addy",
  "formatted_phone_number" : "phone",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 00.00000000000000,
        "lng" : -00.0000000
     },
     "viewport" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 00.0000000000000,
           "lng" : -00.0000000000000
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 00.0000000000000,
           "lng" : -00.0000000000000
        }
     }
  },
```

which I assume is an array. It will pull for 8 different businesses. Whats an easy way for me to style each api request that I receive from google? Im new to php so bare with me if this is easy. I know I can print out HTML and style that, and sense all the data's formatted the same I could do predefined styles as it would pull the same way each time for each array. Or I could have the data pull once a week and save to a sql database for less bandwidth and faster load times. but one step at a time, lets try this first. I want to learn.

```css
.test{
border: 2px solid green;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin: 0 auto;
display:table;
}
```

```html
<?php

    
//The URL with parameters / query string.
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';
$url1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE1&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';
$url2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE2&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';
$url3 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE3&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';
$url4 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE4&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';
$url5 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ID GOES HERE5&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=KEY GOES HERE API';

//Once again, we use file_get_contents to GET the URL in question.
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$contents2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$contents3 = file_get_contents($url3);
$contents4 = file_get_contents($url4);
$contents5 = file_get_contents($url5);
$contents6 = file_get_contents($url6);
$contents7 = file_get_contents($url7);
 
//If $contents is not a boolean FALSE value.
if($contents !== false){
    //Print out the contents.
    echo '<div class="test">'; 
    echo $contents,$contents2,$contents3,$contents4,$contents5;
    echo '</div>'; 
}

var_dump($array);//will equal null.

?>
```

Comment: Did you do a var_dump($contents) to see what is actually returned (if anything). When you wrote about a GET request to an API i was assuming you meant a curl request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can decode the json response data, and print the datas in it.
Also to style each request separately, just add a couple of classes in your style sheet, and print them with that classes.

```
.test{
  border: 2px solid green;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}
.test.test1{
  border-color: red;
}
.test.test2{
  border-color: blue;
}
...
```

```
$contents1 = json_decode($contents1,true);
$contents2 = json_decode($contents2,true);
// ...

echo '<div class="container">'
if($contents1 !== false){
    echo '<div class="test test1">'; 
    echo '<span class="address">' . $contents1['result']['formatted_address'] . "</span>";
    echo '</div>'; 
}
if($contents2 !== false){
    echo '<div class="test test2">'; 
    echo '<span class="address">' . $contents2['result']['formatted_address'] . "</span>";
    echo '</div>'; 
}
echo '</div>'
// ...
```

Also note that It's better to use arrays and loops, to prevent duplicate codes.

Comment: @qwertyyuiop updated the answer and included `json_decode`.

Comment: @qwertyyuiop No problem. welcome to stack overflow. when you got your desired answer, please mark that answer as accepted one. this works as a `solved` label and helps other to know this question is solved. happy codding :)

Comment: can u explain this too me?$contents1['result']['formatted_address']  I know ['result'] would be the array right and ['formatted_address'] is what ur grabbing from array?

Comment: @qwertyyuiop they are not array. they are dictionary (object) : https://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/javascript-basics-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-keyvalue-pairs

Comment: this should work $contents2['result']['reviews']['rating'] but gives string(8) "[rating]" dont i need to specify the key 0 at this point somehow like ['rating[0]']  ???

Comment: @qwertyyuiop this is not part of the json in the question, so i'm not sure. but maybe it's like: `$contents2['result']['reviews'][0]['rating']` (if `reviews` is an array.)